# Instant file sharing between users in PHP

Tags: file, upload, download, instantclient

Working on a rather complex system in which users can directly exchange files with eachother from the website. However is any of these things possible:

EITHER

```
* Have another user download a file which is still being uploaded by another user ( in progress )
```

OR

```
* Make a user automaticly ( instant ) download a file from another users PC through our website
```

OR

```
* Make a user automaticly (instant) download a file from our server ( so it's directly downloaded to the users pc and the progress shown on our website of the download progress, without the normal internet explorer dialog downloading the file or firefox ).
```

Thank you very much in advanced,

Best Regards,
Webcodez.net.

UPDATE: an example would be MSN's file sharing but then through a website instead of application.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news - there is a reason MSN does that in an application. Given users are likely t obe behind NAT (i.e. their computers not reachable) and tha tyou dont want a website abusing your computer to send spam (i.e. open random network connections) websites are LIMITED.

So, you have a nice wish, it is not possible and I am REALLY happy it is not possible. Being a user and so.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Was afraid so already, though would there be any alternatives? Like uploading a file in several parts and each time one part is completed uploading, the user can download that part already just over browser?

Comment: possibly. or go for an application. Try using silverlight in a browser, or flash - but even then.... i would go for a central repository.

Comment: Ok htank you for your response.